# PostgreSQL filter group by individual values

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, postgresql-9.1

I have a query that returns data as shown;

```
name | field | count_1 | count_2 |
-----|-------|---------|---------|
John |  aaa  |    3    |    3    |
John |  bbb  |    3    |    3    |
John |  ccc  |    3    |    3    |
John |  ddd  |    1    |    1    |
Dave |  aaa  |    3    |    3    |
Dave |  bbb  |    3    |    3    |
Dave |  ccc  |    3    |    3    |
Dave |  ddd  |    3    |    3    |
-----|-------|---------|---------|
```

I need to filter this data by the counts where `count_1` and `count_2` are `=3`. In the above case, for John on field `ddd` both counts don't meet the condition so the query should return `Dave` only regardless of the other conditions met by `John` on the other fields. How can I achieve this?

As long as a single count is not met by an individual on the given fields, he should be filtered out.

Comment: To understand correctly, show in the question the output that you want to get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got this right, a `NOT EXISTS` might help you.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (<your query>) x
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM (<your query) y
                                WHERE y.name = x.name
                                      AND (y.count_1 <> 3
                                           OR y.count_2 <> 3));
```

Replace `<your query>` with your query, that gave you the posted result (or use a CTE for that but be aware, that this may cause performance issues in Postgres).

Maybe there is a more elegant solution, that already "short cuts" into your query, but to find such would require more information about your schema and the current query.

Comment: Thanks. This one really helped - though I modified the first part of the query like in Gordon's answer (`WITH t AS (<my-query>) SELECT * FROM t WHERE NOT EXISTS...`)so as to avoid repeating the huge query

Comment: @Clint_A . . . Given that you are using a subquery, it is probably better to have a solution that only references the subquery once.

Answer (score 4):

Use the boolean aggregate [`bool_and()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) in the having clause to get names meetign the conditions:

```
select name
from the_data
group by 1
having bool_and(count_1 = 3 and count_2 = 3)

 name 
------
 Dave
(1 row)
```

You can use the above as a subquery to filter and return original rows (if you need this):

```
select *
from the_data
where name in (
    select name
    from the_data
    group by 1
    having bool_and(count_1 = 3 and count_2 = 3)
    )

 name | field | count_1 | count_2 
------+-------+---------+---------
 Dave | aaa   |       3 |       3
 Dave | bbb   |       3 |       3
 Dave | ccc   |       3 |       3
 Dave | ddd   |       3 |       3
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where count_1 <> 3) over (partition by name) as cnt_1_3,
             count(*) filter (where count_2 <> 3) over (partition by name) as cnt_2_3
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_1_3 = 0 and cnt_2_3 = 0;
```

If you don't want the original rows, I would go for aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having min(count_1) = max(count_1) and min(count_1) = 3 and
       min(count_2) = max(count_2) and min(count_2) = 3;
```

Or you can phrase this as:

```
having sum( (count_1 <> 3)::int ) = 0 and
       sum( (count_2 <> 3)::int ) = 0
```

Note that all the above assume the counts are not `NULL` (which seems reasonable for something called a count).  You can use `NULL`-safe comparison (`is distinct from`) if `NULL` values are a possibility.